# Webpage Print button not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am very new to jQuery and html, and I am trying to make a print button on my webpage. I get the little print image to show up, but clicking on the image does nothing. My cursor doesn't even change when my mouse hovers over the image. I have a jQuery function that is supposed to handle the logic for printing. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**Here is the code that I have so far:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PoliticsHTML_CSS.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css">
<title>Display HTML Table</title>

<script>
$('.printMe').click(function(){
     window.print();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL); 
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$con=mysqli_connect("******","*****","***", "***");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM PoliticsPoll";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

echo "<table border='1' class='pure-table-bordered'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 1</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 2</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 3</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 4</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 5</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 6</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 7</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 8</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 9</th>
<th>Politics Poll Question 10</th>
</tr>";

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<img src="print.png" class="printMe" alt="Print" title="Print"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you add the "click"-handler to a DOM-element that doesn't exists (now).
move your `<script>` after the `<img>` and before `</body>`.

Comment: bonus info: if you move your script at the bottom, you don't need a document.ready because the DOM is ready if the browser parse your javscript ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't realy need to use Jquery for this, try changing your print button to this:

```
<script>
    function Print () {
        window.print()
    }
</script>

<img src="print.png" class="printMe" onClick="Print()" alt="Print" title="Print"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is because the printMe element doesn't exist yet, you need to wait until it has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.printMe').click(function(){
     window.print();
  });
});
```

That tells it to wait until the document has loaded to bind the event handler.